# How does the Miller effect affect a JFET-amplifier stage with tuned-circuit input?

Tags: amplifier, jfet

I'm trying to build a simple JFET amplifier of MW signals (500kHz-1.5MHz) using a ferrite antenna and a variable capacitor to tune the desired station. The schematics is pretty obvious, as seen in the following figure:

[image: Tuned JFET amplifier]

While designing it, I wondered if Miller effect has any impact here, as it will lead to a capacitance between JFET's gate and source and, with source grounded at AC due to \$C_s\$, Miller capacitance will appear in parallel with tuning capacitor \$C_t\$ so, apart of modifying the tuning range (which I can compensate adjusting the self-made coil) I don't see any other obvious harm here. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wondered if Miller effect has any impact here, as it will lead to a
>   capacitance between JFET's gate and source

Miller capacitance is between drain and gate but for JFETs you can usually find types with about 1 pF so go for something like an 2N5486. 1 pF multiplied by voltage gain could be somewhat troublesome at 30 MHz but not at 1 MHz because Ct is going to be several tens of pF to hundreds of pF.

Try it and see and also compare your design with one on the internet using JFETs.

Answer (score 0):

A tuned amplifier is not a wideband amplifier; and the Miller effect is handled differently. In a wideband amplifier, the goal is to reduce the gain of the stage to 1 so the C multiplication does not occur. This is normally done with a Cascode common grid-base-gate output stage. With a tuned amplifier, you have the opportunity to absorb the capacitance into a tuned circuit, so the effect is negated. This is why tuned amplifiers are preferred at RF in single stages. Where is your output tuned circuit? You will need to neutralize with a tapped output coil or some other method. The tuning cap can be a ganged affair.

Comment: "With a tuned amplifier, you have the opportunity to absorb the capacitance into a tuned circuit, so the effect is negated."

So, you confirm my suspicions here: the Miller capacitance will be absorbed into the tuned circuit.